# Python: Get all factors in an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to list out all common factors of the elements in an array in Python, but unable to use gcd() because it only print out the **highest** common factor. Any ways to print all factors of the elements?

```
from math import gcd
def solve(nums):
   if len(nums) == 1:
      return nums[0]

   div = gcd(nums[0], nums[1])

   if len(nums) == 2:
      return div

   for i in range(1, len(nums) - 1):
      div = gcd(div, nums[i + 1])
      if div == 1:
         return div

return div

nums = [15, 81, 78]
print(solve(nums))
```

Comment: The reason for it only printing the greatest common factor is because that is what gcd stands for

Comment: to make sure: You want all divisors common to a list of input numbers?

Answer (score 1):

As the name implies, the GCD is the *greatest* common divisor of a list of numbers. Since every number is uniquely decomposable into primes, this GCD already includes all other factors common to the list of numbers. If you want to find all factors, simply find the factors of the GCD.
If you can use sympy, just use

```
from math import gcd
from sympy import divisors

def get_common_factors(numbers: list):
    # as of python 3.9, gcd accepts multiple numbers
    greatest_common_divisor = gcd(*numbers)
    return divisors(greatest_common_divisor)
```

Otherwise, you can roll your own simple divisors function

```
def divisors(num: int):
    divisors = [div for div in range(1, num + 1) if num % div == 0]
    return divisors
```